# How to delegate a domain to Azure DNS from Azure portal?

Tags: powershell, azure, dns

I found below article from the azure website for domain delegation to Azure DNS.

[Delegate a domain to Azure DNS](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/dns/dns-domain-delegation)

But above article is based on PowerShell . I don't have knowledge in it. I want to do this from azure portal.But i don't find any help for it.

Comment: Delegating a domain to Azure DNS is done from your domain name provider's DNS settings. The PowerShell commands in that article are simply ways of getting info about your zone's nameservers, which must be added to the DNS provider's records. You can get them from the portal too.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Hi assuming you have bought your domain you need to log on to the control panel of the company you purchased the domain from and ammend the "Name servers" to be those assigned by Azure DNS.

In the article you posted, under the section "Finding the name server names" the servers listed in the orange box are the name servers you need to enter in your domain registrar's control panel.  In order for these servers to be assigned you have to have first created the zone in Azure DNS which is set out in this article: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/dns/dns-getstarted-create-dnszone-portal

Once you make this change due to the nature of DNS it can take a while for the changes to work.

Comment: Thanks. I am able to do it now.